# Office file Parsing to PDF on Heroku with Django

Tags: python, django, pdf, heroku, ms-office

I'm looking for a solution to convert doc/xls/ppt files into PDF documents with a Django app on Heroku.

https://github.com/rishihahs/heroku-buildpack-libreoffice

This buildpack puts my slug size above the allowed size, but obviously this would be the best solution. I'm thinking of converting on another server, but would really be nice if I could do it within the heroku app itself. Anyone had this problem and solved it before?

Comment: There's some solutions here that may work for you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891787/an-efficient-way-to-convert-document-to-pdf-format

Comment: You can't use a bounty to prevent your question being closed. Bounties aren't currency to get people to do your work for you.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about @LegoStormtroopr. I don't want anyone doing any work for me, I'm looking for an answer to my problem. I see nothing about closing anyone my question. Asking developers if they have met this problem and know a fix or a workaround is not doing somebody's work.

Comment: Is there any reason why any of the solutions that @ChrisMontanaro linked to won't work?

Comment: Docsplit uses ruby and libreoffice (which puts the slug size over), unoconv needs libreoffice (which puts the slug size over), Pandoc can handle only docx files and not xlsx and ppt files, xtopdf would be awesome if it would be done and would actually handle office files, so far it does not. So no, I did search a lot for a package before asking this question, and I did find that thread :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku support was able to bump my slug size which makes this issue resolved :)